# How to Transfer calls to voice mail in android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there any way by which i can transfer calls to voice mail programmatically?? I am making an application for android in which i will use this feature.

Comment: Can you please share your solution? I am in same requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Detect using: [CALL_STATE_RINGING](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_RINGING) or [LISTEN_CALL_STATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#LISTEN_CALL_STATE)

However, AFAIK, you cannot make API calls to the Telephony service which will allow forwarding to Voicemail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for incoming call. Disconnect the call. If voice mail facility is available on the device then it will ask user to leave voice mail.

Comment: How to send that call into voice mail? Any idea/

Comment: If voice mail facility is active over device then on disconnecting the call it will prompt calling user to leave voice mail....